# Problema de conexão simples C# com MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql

Fala galera estou com o seguinte erro ao tentar fazer um insert simples de uma atividade no meu banco mysql "System.ArgumentException: 'O formato da cadeia de inicialização não está de acordo com a especificação iniciada no índice 57.", ao fazer algumas alterações para tentar resolver o problema só mudou o índice do erro alguem pode me ajudar a solucionar o problema?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sugiro dar uma lida [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/53279), fica mais difícil ajudar com imagem, alguns de nós nem podem ver a imagem por limitações na rede

Comment: Poste o código ao invés da imagem.

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na sua connection string está ssl:true, troque por SslMode=required
E no campo password, use PASSWORD=\"\"

`string caminho = "SERVER=TestePorta;DATABASE=db_exemplo;UID=root;PASSWORD=\"\";SslMode=required";`

Comment: Após as alterações ocorreu o seguinte erro : System.ArgumentException: 'Option not supported.
Parameter name: ssl' .

Comment: Então troque o parâmetro SSL=true por SslMode=required

Comment: Opa amigo obrigado resolveu o meu problema!!